# How to display title with month and year in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I need to display only month and year in title. How to solve this. I can display in date picker but title is display with day.

```
    scanExpireDate = (CheckoutEditText) findViewById(R.id.scan_expire_date);
    scanExpireDate.setTextView();



public void onDatePickerClick(View view){
                Utils.customDatePicker(this, datePickerListener);
        }

        private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                String cardExpireDateFormt = Utils.getCardExpireDate(selectedYear,  selectedMonth);
                if(isCardScanned){
                    scanExpireDate.setText(cardExpireDateFormt);
                }else{
                    cardExpireDate.setText(cardExpireDateFormt);
                }
            }
        };

        public static DatePickerDialog customDatePicker(Activity activity, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int cardYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int cardMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int cardDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, datePickerListener, cardYear,cardMonth,cardDay);
        Date minDate = new Date();
        c.set(cardYear, cardMonth, cardDay - 1, 0, 0);
        minDate.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTime());

        try {
            Field[] datePickerDialogFields = datePickerDialog.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
                if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                    datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(datePickerDialog);
                    Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType()
                            .getDeclaredFields();
                    for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                        if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName()) || "mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                            datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                            Object dayPicker = new Object();
                            dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                            ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            datePickerDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return datePickerDialog;
    }
```

How to remove the day in title?

it displays like this..
   [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also look at better picker which has a mm/yy date picker dialog

Answer (score 1):

For achieving that, you need to customize datepicker dialogue..

please refer this link

http://www.open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=56

or you can simply use

`datePickerDialog.setTitle()` method

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
class CustomerDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {
   public CustomerDatePickerDialog(Context context,OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
      super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
   }
   @Override
   public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
      super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
      setTitle(month+" "+year);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the problem, but i haven't find the perfect solution. but i try to use

```
datePickerDialog.setCustomTitle(new TextView(context));
```

to remove the title, but even has a line in the top.

//update 
more perfect solution:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
datePickerDialog.setCustomTitle(frameLayout);
```